# How to access child object properties?

Tags: c, gtk3

I'm trying to get the text property from an entry in a dialog with the following code:

```
GtkWidget   *dialog, *entry;
gchar       *text;

entry = gtk_entry_new();

dialog = create_dialog();

...

gtk_container_child_get(GTK_CONTAINER(dialog), entry, "text", text, NULL);
```

and i'm getting the following:

```
(textview:3079): Gtk-WARNING **: /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.4.2/./gtk/gtkcontainer.c:919: container class `GtkDialog' has no child property named `text'
```

The dialog contains a label and an entry with two buttons.

Comment: Why don't you simply use gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (entry))?

Answer (score 1):

You're misinterpreting what `gtk_container_child_get` does. It doesn't return a child's property, but it returns so-called child-properties. Those are properties that aren't associated with just the parent or just the child, but rather with their relation.

`"text"` is not such a property. You should just use `gtk_entry_get_text` like Szilárd suggests.